# Does anyone know how I can replace the DHCP Reservation MAC address for an IP using powershell?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, dhcp

Server Win 2012 (not r2)

I want to replace some DHCP reservation's mac address only in a single scope. Preferably using a txt/csv and matching on PC name.

I was loooking at the DHCP options in powershell and it looks like i have to delete the Reservation and re-add it.

Does anyone know how I can replace the DHCP Reservation MAC address for an IP using 'Power-shell'?

Eg: ip=10.10.10.1
Name = Computer1`
MAC = 00-01-02-03-04 change this value only 00-02-03-05-06

Thanks
Roger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows 2012+ there is a DHCP Server module for PowerShell. Check out this function:

[Set-DhcpServerv4Reservation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj590690%28v=wps.620%29.aspx)

A simple search for "dhcp server powershell" would have found you the module as the firs result, and "dhcp server reservation powershell" would even give you a blog with samples.. Please show some effort first.

Comment: I had found the ADD/Remove and Get cmdlets, but somehow i missed the set command. That was why I was thinking i had to Remove and re-add (using the Add - Remove cmdlets) as described above.  I think it was unfair to accuse of no effort being spent as I mention in the post of finding the DHCP options, unfortunately I missed seeing the one actually needed.

Comment: Sorry. The "no effort" part was mainly due to the second result from the google search I showed above: http://blogs.technet.com/b/teamdhcp/archive/2012/11/21/bulk-load-dhcp-reservations-using-dhcp-powershell.aspx  It mentions the Set command with an explanation(that it modifies the entry). Misreading Technet is always allowed :). It just seemed to be explained clearly in the other google results. Also, I just guess people are getting on my nerves lately. There are too many users here who ask for full solutions when 2 minutes of reading would give you the answer.